# Remove poster attribute from video

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm loading a video in FancyBox 3 from Slider Revolution.

When the user clicks on the play button image, the video loads in the lightbox but uses the play button as the poster image.

I've tried to remove that poster image but it isn't working.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({

    onInit: function (instance, current) {
        $('.fancybox-video').attr('poster', '');
    },

    // also tried this
    // type: 'ajax',
    // afterShow: function() {
    //     $('.fancybox-video').attr('poster', '');
    // }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, the answer is found in the [documentation](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options):

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    video: {
        tpl:
            '<video class="fancybox-video" controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="">' +
            '<source src="{{src}}" type="{{format}}" />' +
            'Sorry, your browser doesn\'t support embedded videos, <a href="{{src}}">download</a> and watch with your favorite video player!' +
            "</video>",
        format: "", // custom video format
        autoStart: true
        }, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `removeAttr()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

`$('.fancybox-video').removeAttr('poster');`

Comment: The fancybox element is not available until you click the link (play button image) so I can't remove the poster attribute because the element doesn't exist until the link is clicked.

Comment: Can you post a codepen of your full js/html/css? That'd be really helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for following up but I resolved this issue. I added my answer but can't accept it until tomorrow.